# Next-auth Ошибка 400 в Яндекс OAuth

Tags: auth, nextjs, oauth, next.js

Пытаюсь реализовать авторизацию через яндексId в своем nextjs14 веб-приложении, получаю ошибку 400 "redirect_uri не совпадает с Callback URL, указанным при регистрации приложения".
Использую next-auth с [провадером yandex](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/yandex)(На localhost)

Не понимаю, где нужно передавать redirect_uri.

#app\api\auth[...nextauth]\route.ts

```
...),
    // ...add more providers here
    YandexProvider({
      clientId: process.env.YANDEX_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.YANDEX_CLIENT_SECRET
    })
  ]
...
```

#\app\login\page.js

```
  <button onClick={() =>
      signIn("yandex")
    }
  >
    Войти с ЯндексID
  </button>
```

Пробовал передавать так(C разными вариациями)

```
  signIn("yandex", {
    callbackUrl: "http://localhost:3000/",
  })
```

Пробовал разные redirect_uri
[image: Перепробовал все варианты которые нагуглил]

Не понимаю как это должно быть реализовано.

Возможно я потратил кучу времени зря и локально авторизация и не работает, тогда как мне убедиться, что всё правильно описано.